# Debian 6 installation DVD required

Tags: debian, install

I just want to install the operating system and SSH printserver .
I just burned the first DVD of the 8 avaible for the amd64 architecture. 
How many DVDs should i burn in order the operating system to install ?
Note: Connection is slow as hell that is why i choose DVD solution

Comment: I'd point you to the [Debian CD FAQ](http://www.debian.org/CD/faq/), but the answer to [your question](http://www.debian.org/CD/faq/#search-for-package) is not up-to-date there! I don't know where to find the contents of the squeeze DVDs.

Comment: What is an ssh printserver?

Comment: late response but i think i forgot a comma

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Only the first is enough. It will even have at least one complete Desktop environment, GNOME. The way the content is organised is such that the most popular packages (according to [popcon](http://popcon.debian.org/)) are in the earlier discs.

Comment: It's kind of funny that some distros number their CDs/DVDs and people are confused. Same thing [happened](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/4311/single-cd-install-of-a-rhel-like-distribution/4324#4324) for Fedora too :)